# Adaptive Images: CE Image vs. Standard EE Image Manipulations

Tags: ce-image

I made a site which uses CE Image for adaptive images. It uses the instructions at https://www.aaron-gustafson.com/notebook/adaptive-images-in-expressionengine-with-ce-image/ to do this. You can see this in action if you search "srcset" in the first link's source code.

But I'm wondering, wouldn't the standard image manipulations be just as good? I'm talking about the "Constrain or Crop" part of your Upload Directory, where when you upload an image, EE automatically creates derivatives of it.

Or maybe I'm oversimplifying things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference is the amount of features and optinos ce image gives you. things like limiting filesize, compression etc.  Also, CE image doesn't rely on images uploaded through EE. It handles external images, and saves the images locally. But if it's just resizing/cropping the EE mechanism works just fine

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. With EE's native image resizing, it also doesn't suffer the desaturated look that CE Image produces. (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-image/viewthread/1085) I think CE Image is great for other stuff, but for just this, I'm going to stick with EE native.